# Domain Access and vagrant

Tags: domain-access, subsites

I have made a copy of a Drupal 7 site with several sub-domains managed through [domain access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) to a vagrant VM so I can experiment with it.

I have my vagrant set up so I reach it through localhost on the host machine. eg:

```
localhost:4567/default.basesite.com/
```

Where `default.basesite.com` is the name of the folder my site resides in and is configured as the base path for the drupal install in the virtualhost file on the VM. It is also the name of the original live site.

That gets me to the home page. However, the sub-domains are broken so when I try to visit them the link generated internally by domain access is of the form:

```
subsite.basesite.com/default.basesite.com/whatever...
```

Which is clearly not going to work. If I try to manually generate the link as I would expect it to look, eg:

```
localhost:4567/subsite.basesite.com/
```

I get a 404 not found error.

How do I configure Domain Access with Vagrant to take in to account the local host setup? Do I need to re-direct rule or is something else going on?